# Creating subTable within subTable with PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, xhtml, primefaces

I need to know how to create table such as below in PrimeFaces. 
I have tried with subTree within subTree but it's not allowed in PrimeFaces.

For this I have 3 classes:
Product: name, containing array of Items
Item: name, containing array of content
Content: name

I need also to perform for loop but it seems it's allowed in panelGrid.

Col1.............Col2..........Col3

---

Product1......Item 1.......content 1

....................................content 2

....................................content 3

................... Item 2.......content 5

....................................content 6

---

Product2......Item 3.......content 9

....................................content 10

....................Item 4.......content 15

.....................................content 17